# Why isn't the Provider Package changing the background image?

Tags: flutter, background, state, stateful, flutter-onpressed

I've added the provider package to my application where I have two screen. When the user clicks on a small image on the app it changes the main background image on the other screen. I've called the Provider and classes on both screens but it just isn't returning the 'myValue' inside Positioned.fill.

Homepage screen with the background image that needs to change:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_app_background/small_images.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';


void main() => runApp(MyApp());


class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ChangeNotifierProvider<MyModel>(
      create: (context) => MyModel(),
      child: MaterialApp(
        title: 'Title',
        home: HomePage(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return Scaffold(
        extendBodyBehindAppBar: true,
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Background Image', style: TextStyle(
              color: Colors.black,
              fontSize: 16,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
          ),
          iconTheme: IconThemeData(color: Colors.white),
          actions: <Widget>[
            IconButton(
              icon: Icon(Icons.settings, color: Colors.black,),
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.push(
                  context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SmallImages()),
                );
              },
            ),
          ],
          backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
          elevation: 0.0,
        ),
        body: Stack(
          children: <Widget>
          [
            Positioned.fill(
              child: GestureDetector(
                child: Consumer<MyModel>(
                  builder: (context, myModel, child) {
                    return myModel.bgImage;
                    // return myValue;
                  },
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      );
    }
}

class MyModel extends ChangeNotifier {
  Image bgImage = Image.asset('images/background_image.jpeg', fit: BoxFit.fill);

}
```

Small Images screen where the user taps on small image to change the background in Homepage.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_app_background/main.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';


class SmallImages extends StatefulWidget {
  static int tappedGestureDetector = 1;

  @override
  _SmallImagesState createState() => _SmallImagesState();
}

class _SmallImagesState extends State<SmallImages> {

  List<bool> isSelected;

  void initState() {
    isSelected = [true, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false];
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final myModel = Provider.of<MyModel>(context,listen:true); //default for listen is `true`
    return Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: Text('Small Image', style: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.black, fontSize: 16, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
            ),
            iconTheme: IconThemeData(color: Colors.white),
            actions: <Widget>[
              IconButton(
                icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_left, color: Colors.black,),
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.pop(
                    context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => HomePage()),
                  );
                },
              ),
            ],
            backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
            elevation: 0.0,
          ),
          body: Material(
            child: GestureDetector(
              child: MaterialApp(
                  builder: (context, snapshot) {
                    return GridView.count(
                      crossAxisCount: 1,
                      childAspectRatio: 1.0,
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
                      mainAxisSpacing: 0.0,
                      crossAxisSpacing: 0.0,
                      children: [
                        GridView(
                          gridDelegate:
                          SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(crossAxisCount: 3,
                            childAspectRatio: MediaQuery
                                .of(context)
                                .size
                                .width /
                                (MediaQuery
                                    .of(context)
                                    .size
                                    .height / 2),
                          ),
                          children: [
                              GestureDetector(
                                onTap: () {
                                  setState(() {
                                    SmallImages.tappedGestureDetector = 1;
                                  });
                                  myModel.bgImage = Image.asset('images/iceland_background.jpg');
                                },
                                child: Container(
                                  height: 100,
                                  width: 107,
                                  decoration: BoxDecoration(border: SmallImages
                                      .tappedGestureDetector == 1
                                      ? Border.all(
                                      color: Color(0xff2244C7), width: 1.0)
                                      : Border
                                      .all(color: Colors.transparent,),),
                                  child: Image.asset(
                                    'images/nightsky_image.png',
                                  ),
                                ),
                            ),
                            Consumer<MyModel>(
                              builder: (context, myModel, child) {
                                return GestureDetector(
                                  onTap: () {
                                    setState(() {
                                      SmallImages.tappedGestureDetector = 2;
                                    }); // <-- replaced 'tapped' and 'other'
                                  },
                                  child: Container(
                                    height: 100,
                                    width: 107,
                                    decoration: BoxDecoration(border: SmallImages
                                        .tappedGestureDetector == 2
                                        ? Border.all(
                                        color: Color(0xff2244C7), width: 1.0)
                                        : Border
                                        .all(color: Colors.transparent,),),
                                    child: Image.asset(
                                      'images/own_image.png',
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                );
                              },
                            ),
                            Consumer<MyModel>(
                              builder: (context, myModel, child) {
                                return GestureDetector(
                                  onTap: () {
                                    setState(() {
                                      SmallImages.tappedGestureDetector = 3;
                                    }); // <-- replaced 'tapped' and 'other'
                                  },
                                  child: Container(
                                    height: 100,
                                    width: 107,
                                    decoration: BoxDecoration(border: SmallImages
                                        .tappedGestureDetector == 3
                                        ? Border.all(
                                        color: Color(0xff2244C7), width: 1.0)
                                        : Border
                                        .all(color: Colors.transparent,),),
                                    child: Image.asset(
                                      'images/iceland_image.png',
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                );
                              },
                            ),
                          ].toList(),
                        ),
                      ],
                    );
                  }),
            ),
          ),
        );
  }
}
```

Comment: Hey guys, I need some help with this, I updated the code above with details from the answer but still having problems. It seems bgImage isn't recognised in the Class with using a final so I changed it to an Image and it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should wrap material app with provider:

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Provider<MyModel>(
      create: (context) => MyModel(),
      child: MaterialApp(
        title: 'Title',
        home: HomePage(),
      );
    )

  }
}
```

if you want it to rebuild some widget on change of the MyModel, you should extend MyModel with ChangeNotifer like this:

```
class MyModel extends ChangeNotifier{
final bgImage = //someimage
```

and instead of Provider around the `MaterialApp` you should use `ChangeNotifierProvider` like this:

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ChangeNotifierProvider<MyModel>(
      create: (context) => MyModel(),
      child: MaterialApp(
        title: 'Title',
        home: HomePage(),
      );
    )

  }
}
```

after that you should include provider inside the widget like this:

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final mymodel = Provider.of<MyModel>(context); // injecting the provider
    return Container ( .....
```

and you can use background image inside the container like this,

```
color:mymodel.bgImage
```

as soon as you will change the `mymodel.bgImage` widget will be rebuilt automatically.

if you are planning to rebuild specific `widget` inside the `widget tree`, you can remove injection such as this in this case `final mymodel = Provider.of<MyModel>(context);` and just wrap that specific `widget` with `Consumer<MyModel>` like this:

```
Container(
  child:Consumer<MyModel>(
    builder: (context, myModel, child) {
    return Text("${myModel.text}"); // supposing that `text` is inside the `MyModel`
  },
)
```

if you don't need child and context to use under the Container you can do it like this:

```
child:Consumer<MyModel>(
    builder: (_, myModel, _) {
```

example of changing the `myModel.bgImage` will be something like this:

```
FlatButton(
onPressed: (val){
  myModel.image = otherImage  // changeing the value of my model while pressing on the button

  }
)
```

changing the value of my model while pressing on the button will rebuild any widget which injects `MyModel Provider` and Provider `listen` property is set to `true`,(listen property is set to `true` by default)

example of `listen` property:

```
final mymodel = Provider.of<MyModel>(context,listen:false) //default for listen is `true`
```

Comment: Thanks but it's still not working. I'm having a problem with adding 'val' within the FlatButton. It says 'The argument type 'Null Function(dynamic)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'void Function()'.

Comment: don't add anything leave it empty

Comment: and that FlatButton is just an example you can have anything there,

Comment: Thanks, it's not recognising the bgImage because it's on a different screen.

Comment: lib/small_images.dart:74:43: Error: The setter 'bgImage' isn't defined for the class 'MyModel'.
 - 'MyModel' is from 'package:flutter_app_background/main.dart' ('lib/main.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing setter, or defining a setter or field named 'bgImage'.
                                  myModel.bgImage = Image.asset('images/iceland_background.jpg');
                                          ^^^^^^^

Comment: kidding? You should have bgImage property in MyModel class to actually use it

Comment: I am going to sleep read my answer couple of time and you will figure it out for sure.